# terminal, totem, nautilus etc. not working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nautilus, gnome-terminal, totem

In my Ubuntu 18.04 following problems are occurring

1. Terminal not opening from context menu
2. Totem (default video player) not opening from "open with" context menu
3. Folders are not opening when double clicking on it or open from context menu also failing.

etc.

So What can I do for these problem?

Comment: context menu item calls .desktop files ... looking in some default directories ... if target programs are snaps (for example), then *.desktop files are not present in seeked folders...

Comment: so how can i find *.desktop files in seeked folders? where seeked folders are?

Answer (score 1):

It may be occurring due to a problem with gstreamer. Run:

```
sudo apt purge gstreamer1.0-vaapi
```